# CentOS Stream 8 - DNF Broken - Unable to Run Update/Upgrade

Tags: centos, centos8, dnf

I thought I successfully upgraded from CentOS8 to Centos Stream 8, however I was never able to get dnf distro-sync to work.  Now DNF appears to be broken and dnf upgrade throws unsatisfied dependencies for libsmartcols.so.1 in relation to DNF itself.

dnf distro-sync:
When running the sync, the following appears:

```
Error: 
 Problem: The operation would result in removing the following protected packages: setup
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

I tried every possible combination of --skip-broken, --nobest --allowerasing, etc. to resolve.  Tried using the vault versions, no difference.  All of the old CentOS repos were removed, so the only repos in the /etc/yum.repos.d/ folder are *-Stream-*.  I do not have any EPEL repos installed at this time.

cat /etc/centos-release => CentOS Stream release 8

The server survives reboots and seems to work correctly for everything else.

When running dnf -y upgrade -v, the following results:

```
dnf -y upgrade -v
Loaded plugins: builddep, changelog, config-manager, copr, debug, debuginfo-install, download, generate_completion_cache, groups-manager, needs-restarting, playground, repoclosure, repodiff, repograph, repomanage, reposync
DNF version: 4.7.0
cachedir: /var/cache/dnf
User-Agent: constructed: 'libdnf (CentOS Stream 8; generic; Linux.x86_64)'
repo: using cache for: appstream
appstream: using metadata from Tue 08 Feb 2022 07:27:22 PM EST.
repo: using cache for: baseos
baseos: using metadata from Tue 08 Feb 2022 07:26:22 PM EST.
repo: using cache for: extras
extras: using metadata from Tue 08 Feb 2022 04:08:34 PM EST.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:26:35 ago on Thu 10 Feb 2022 12:44:57 PM EST.
--> Starting dependency resolution
---> Package dnf-plugins-core.noarch 4.0.21-8.el8 will be upgraded
---> Package dnf-plugins-core.noarch 4.0.21-10.el8 will be an upgrade
---> Package libdnf.x86_64 0.63.0-5.el8 will be upgraded
---> Package libdnf.x86_64 0.63.0-7.el8 will be an upgrade
---> Package python3-dnf-plugins-core.noarch 4.0.21-8.el8 will be upgraded
---> Package python3-dnf-plugins-core.noarch 4.0.21-10.el8 will be an upgrade
---> Package python3-hawkey.x86_64 0.63.0-5.el8 will be upgraded
---> Package python3-hawkey.x86_64 0.63.0-7.el8 will be an upgrade
---> Package python3-libdnf.x86_64 0.63.0-5.el8 will be upgraded
---> Package python3-libdnf.x86_64 0.63.0-7.el8 will be an upgrade
--> Finished dependency resolution
Dependencies resolved.
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                      Architecture                               Version                                             Repository                                  Size
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrading:
 dnf-plugins-core                                             noarch                                     4.0.21-10.el8                                       baseos                                      71 k
 libdnf                                                       x86_64                                     0.63.0-7.el8                                        baseos                                     701 k
 python3-dnf-plugins-core                                     noarch                                     4.0.21-10.el8                                       baseos                                     230 k
 python3-hawkey                                               x86_64                                     0.63.0-7.el8                                        baseos                                     116 k
 python3-libdnf                                               x86_64                                     0.63.0-7.el8                                        baseos                                     778 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================
Upgrade  5 Packages

Total size: 1.9 M
Downloading Packages:
[SKIPPED] dnf-plugins-core-4.0.21-10.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                                                                      
[SKIPPED] libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                                                                                 
[SKIPPED] python3-dnf-plugins-core-4.0.21-10.el8.noarch.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                                                              
[SKIPPED] python3-hawkey-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                                                                         
[SKIPPED] python3-libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                                                                                                                         
Using rpmkeys executable at /usr/bin/rpmkeys to verify signatures
Running transaction check
Error: transaction check vs depsolve:
libsmartcols.so.1()(64bit) is needed by libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64
libsmartcols.so.1(SMARTCOLS_2.25)(64bit) is needed by libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64
libsmartcols.so.1(SMARTCOLS_2.28)(64bit) is needed by libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64
libsmartcols.so.1(SMARTCOLS_2.29)(64bit) is needed by libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64
libsmartcols.so.1(SMARTCOLS_2.30)(64bit) is needed by libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64
libsmartcols.so.1()(64bit) is needed by python3-hawkey-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64
libsmartcols.so.1()(64bit) is needed by python3-libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64
libsmartcols.so.1(SMARTCOLS_2.25)(64bit) is needed by python3-libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64
libsmartcols.so.1(SMARTCOLS_2.27)(64bit) is needed by python3-libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64
libsmartcols.so.1(SMARTCOLS_2.28)(64bit) is needed by python3-libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64
libsmartcols.so.1(SMARTCOLS_2.29)(64bit) is needed by python3-libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64
libsmartcols.so.1(SMARTCOLS_2.30)(64bit) is needed by python3-libdnf-0.63.0-7.el8.x86_64
To diagnose the problem, try running: 'rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest'.
You probably have corrupted RPMDB, running 'rpm --rebuilddb' might fix the issue.
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
```

I have tried cleaning the packages (dnf clean all), removing the cache files, individually trying to update/upgrade each package, etc..  I'm out of ideas.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Afer a couple more hours of trying, I was able to resolve it by performing the following:

1. Copy a CentOS-Base.repo file from another server
2. Edit the repo file to reflect the vault.centos.org location, turn off gpgcheck
3. dnf clean all
4. dnf install libsmartcols-2.32.1-28.el8

Ran dnf -y upgrade again and it worked.  Go figure.

Hopefully, this will help someone else with the same or similar issue.